# Issue with kafka consumer offset checker command

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, kafka-consumer-api

I have 40 topics under group , for around 2 days kafka-consumer-groups.sh work fine, but after that it will give below error, and it will not come back until we create new group.

ERROR: Consumer group  with protocol type ' ' is not  a valid consumer group

What might be the cause for this issue?

Comment: What version of Kafka are you using?

Comment: Kafka version 0.10.2

Comment: Were there active consumers in the group when you received the error? Also, do you use the new consumer or the old one?

Comment: Yes, there are active consumers which are recieving messages, what do you mean by old or new consumer?

Comment: I mean whether consumer offsets are stored in ZooKeeper (old consumer) or in Kafka itself (new consumer). If you are passing a `--zookeeper` argument to the tool you are using the old consumer, and if you are passing a `--bootstrap-server` argument, you are using the new consumer.

Comment: New consumer --bootstrap-server

Comment: Can you reproduce it every time after waiting for 2 days? Are you using any custom configuration for your brokers or topics or consumers? Sorry for asking questions.

Comment: Does the client and broker version match?